# Byte Array & binary reading - Debug environment for testing/development?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm (near) completely new to this topic and reading a lot on this. Books, Stackexchange, blogs and so on. You know, the common for a developer. I feel that a "big picture understanding" are more easy to achieve when you can debug and test urself into what you read about. I find a lot of theoretical info but less of a practical way to try "unplugged".

My ideas so far is approximatly this:
`byte[]`, `BitConverter.GetBytes`/`BitConverter.ToInt32`, `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` are heavily involved here together with some kind of positions where the array starts. Like as if first 4 bytes in a datagram contains of a msg, then startindex going to be 4 for the sessionid? All of this feels like heavy stuff for the purpose.

Is there a better method to pack/unpack such arrays? 
The messages/datagrams are max 64kb in size and never broaded over different messages.

> More specific: I want to simulate (console app i.e.) a
>   incoming packet and unpack to the information that useful for my
>   system. Then opposite, transfer a answer back to a byte array. 
>   How would a good sample class for this purpose looks like/be handled? How to code /
>   decode into it? The protocol specifications have fixed bytes for the packet. I will leave an 
>   example below (not from the real specification though);

```
// One Packet 
// 
// Description   -> |Identifier|name length|message length|    name   |    message   |
// Size in bytes -> |     4    |     4     |       4      |name length|message length|
```

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve instead. Handling bits/bytes is just means to an end (eller hur man nu säger)

Comment: Som man säger i Dalarna? :-). I want to achieve a "offline" simple environment (like have output of success/unsuccess in a console app) that can pack/unpack such methods, so I can develope and understand the process more easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases you do not read/write binary information yourself. There are several frameworks that can serialize classes/structs to/from binary data. The `BinaryFormatter` or [protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) are two ways.

But if you want to try this yourself I suggest that you just use a `FileStream` since it works exactly as any other stream (a bit simplified statement but almost true ;) Use `BinaryWriter` to write information and `BinaryReader` to read.

There is no reason to handle a `byte[]` array directly. You can always initialize a `MemoryStream` with it to gain access to the `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter`

The important thing is that you read/write the fields in exactly the same order.

### Update

Example using your updated question:

```
// Description   -> |Identifier|name length|message length|    name   |    message   |
// Size in bytes -> |     4    |     4     |       4      |name length|message length|

using (var stream  = new MemoryStream(yourByteBuffer))
{
   using (reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
   {
       var identifier = reader.ReadInt32();
       var nameLength = reader.ReadInt32();
       var msgLength = reader.ReadInt32();
       var name = reader.ReadChars(nameLength);
       var msg = reader.ReadChars(msgLength);
   }
}

// to get a string from the chars:
var message = new string(msg);
```

Comment: Superb, what a relief!! That snippet was enough to get me understand the whole handling. I'm not surprised. When you do much with less code, your probably on right track ;).

Answer (score 0):

The [`System.IO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx) contains the types used to work with files and streams of bytes. Many of these include examples, eg. opening a file to read as a byte Stream: [FileStream Constructor (String, FileMode)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47ek66wy.aspx).